# How to read a .txt file using arm-assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, nasm

I have just started learning on arm-assembly code, with few basic examples. I need some help how to read a .txt file using assembly code (ARM). I tried nasm, it is running fine. But my requirement is to run for arm code (on Linux), whose syntax I am not familiar. Tried multiple things as per online blogs, none of them worked for my case.

Below is the nasm code which worked:

```
[SECTION .text]

global _start

_start:
    xor     eax, eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     ecx, ecx
    xor     edx, edx

    jmp     stub

openf:
    pop     ebx

    mov     al, byte 5      ; syscall 5, open
    xor     ecx, ecx
    int     0x80

    mov     esi, eax
    jmp     readloop

readloop:
    mov     ebx, esi
    mov     al, byte 3      ; syscall 3, read
    sub     esp, 1          ; reserve memory on stack for read byte
    lea     ecx, [esp]      ; load effective address of that memory
    mov     dl, byte 1      ; read count, 1 byte
    int     0x80            ; call read

    xor     ebx, ebx
    cmp     ebx, eax
    je      exit

    mov     al, 4           ; syscall 4, write
    mov     bl, 1           ; file descriptor 1, stdout
    mov     dl, 1           ; write count, 1 byte
    int     0x80            ; call write (4)

    add     esp, 1
    jmp     readloop

exit:
    mov     al, byte 1
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     0x80            ; call exit (1)

stub:
    call    openf
    db      'flag.txt'
```

In brief, my task is to read the 'flag' file, using arm-assembly source code, whose content is the solution for my task. Any help is greatly appreciated as it will help me in learning assembly-code faster.

**Updated:**
I tried using SWI, and below is the code to read & print:

```
    @@@ OPEN INPUT FILE, READ INTEGER FROM FILE, PRINT IT, CLOSE INPUT FILE
    .equ SWI_Open, 0x66 @open a file
    .equ SWI_Close,0x68 @close a file
    .equ SWI_PrChr,0x00 @ Write an ASCII char to Stdout
    .equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 @ Write a null-ending string
    .equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b @ Write an Integer
    .equ SWI_RdInt,0x6c @ Read an Integer from a file
    .equ Stdout, 1 @ Set output target to be Stdout
    .equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 @ Stop execution
    
    .global _start
    .text
    _start:
    
    @ print an initial message to the screen
    mov R0,#Stdout @print an initial message
    ldr R1, =Message1 @ load address of Message1 label
    swi SWI_PrStr @ display message to Stdout
    
    @ == Open an input file for reading =============================
    @ if problems, print message to Stdout and exit
    ldr r0,=InFileName @ set Name for input file
    mov r1,#0 @ mode is input
    swi SWI_Open @ open file for input
    
    @ Save the file handle in memory:
    ldr r1,=InFileHandle @ if OK, load input file handle
    str r0,[r1] @ save the file handle
    
    @ == Read integers until end of file =============================
    RLoop:
    ldr r0,=InFileHandle @ load input file handle
    ldr r0,[r0]
    swi SWI_RdInt @ read the integer into R0
    bcs EofReached @ Check Carry-Bit (C): if= 1 then EOF reached
    @ print the integer to Stdout
    mov r1,r0 @ R1 = integer to print
    mov R0,#Stdout @ target is Stdout
    swi SWI_PrInt
    mov R0,#Stdout @ print new line
    ldr r1, =NL
    swi SWI_PrStr
    bal RLoop @ keep reading till end of file
    @ == End of file ===============================================
    EofReached:
    mov R0, #Stdout @ print last message
    ldr R1, =EndOfFileMsg
    swi SWI_PrStr
    
    .data
    .align
    InFileHandle: .skip 4
    InFileName: .asciz "newlog.txt"
    FileOpenInpErrMsg: .asciz "Failed to open input file \n"
    EndOfFileMsg: .asciz "End of file reached\n"
    ColonSpace: .asciz": "
    NL: .asciz "\n " @ new line 
    Message1: .asciz "Hello World! \n"
```

When I run this, I get the below error:

```
    $ qemu-arm myshell
    qemu: unhandled CPU exception 0x2 - aborting
    R00=00000001 R01=00010126 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
    R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
    R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=000100e0 R11=00000000
    R12=00000000 R13=f6fff9b0 R14=00000000 R15=00008080
    PSR=00000010 ---- A usr32
    qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    Aborted
```

Comment: ARM  is an entirely different cpu architecture. Either get somebody to translate it for you or learn ARM assembly.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree with you. I don't want above nasm code to be translated, instead if someone could show me how to read & print the file using arm-assembly code, that would help.

Comment: Not enough information. Specifically, what's the ARM environment that you've got? Is it Linux? iOS? Android? File reading is not a purely assembly operation, it requires cooperation from the OS (i. e. syscalls and/or RTL), and the community needs to know which OS is it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. It's required to code in ARM running on Linux.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT this question and it gave me usable code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to learn the basics of the ARM assembly. Like, what the commands are, what the registers are, etc. The sample in the question is for an Intel x86 CPU. ARM is a different architecture, so the difference is not that in syntax; the commands, the registers, and even some of the general ideas are not those of Intel. For example, on ARM, most arithmetic commands use three registers, not two like on Intel (`a:=b+c` instead of `a:=a+b`). On the other hand, ARM doesn't support arithmetic operations on memory locations - you have to load into a register first.

Anyways, an intro to ARM is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer like this. Read up. *The learning strategy depends on whether you are familiar with any assembly (e. g. Intel x86), and whether you're familiar with programming in general.* Low level programming is a rather different beast; if all you know is C or Python, there will have to be some major mental model realignment. If you know x86 assembly, you'd want to start with an [ARM assembler manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABFCEEG.html).

If you are new to programming in general, **stop messing with assembly and learn a high level language first**. I'm serious here.

---

All that said, when it comes to file reading, Linux syscalls it is. The ARM convention is: syscall # goes into R7, arguments go into R0..R5. You want syscalls 2 (open), 0 (read), 3 (close). The command to execute a syscall is `swi` (in old assemblers), `svc #0` (if targeting ARMv7+ in Thumb-2 mode, and the assembler supports it).

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: look like the syscall sequence in the latest edit of the question, the one that goes

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 @ Write a null-ending string
...
swi SWI_PrStr @ display message to Stdout
```

comes from ARM specific syscall spec, which is unrelated to the Linux/ARM syscall interface, apart from the fact they're both syscalls. There is a first party ARM simulator that supports them, but the OP is not targeting that.

Comment: Thanks Seva for your answer. I am already working on high-level languages node.js, python etc, but first time I am going to arm-assembly, that's why getting some issues in learning. As your input, I tried using SWI as per your comments, and updated my problem with code above. Getting some error, could you please take a look once? Or else please provide a code-snippet for the pseudo-code you have suggested, as it's a bit new for me to understand.

Comment: I don't have qemu-arm and can't test, but my sources claim the syscall convention on Linux/ARM is different. Read my last paragraph - r7 to syscall # (1 for write), SWI #0. Try with the "print string" piece.